# Protractor - run specific test as mobile device

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a feature that acts differently for mobile web / desktop. My media query is running on device-width, for example:

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
... 
}`

This means that I cannot just change browser size (it will not work):

`browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480);//will not be affected by 'device-size' media query`

I found an option to change `chromeOptions` on device capabilities. I tried using this with `multiCapabilities`:

```
'use strict';

var config = require('infra-gruntfile/protractor-conf').config;

// old capabilities
// config.capabilities = {
//   browserName: 'chrome'
// };

config.multiCapabilities =
[
  {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    name: 'Unnamed Job',
    count: 1,
    shardTestFiles: false,
    maxInstances: 10,
    chromeOptions: {
      'mobileEmulation': {
        'deviceName': 'Apple iPhone 4'
      },
      args: [
        'incognito',
        'disable-extensions'
      ]
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
      browser: 'ALL'
    },
    specs: ['app/**/*.mobile.spec.js']
  },
  {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['!app/**/*.mobile.spec.js']
  }
]

module.exports.config = config;
```

It looks like `specs` doesn't work (I was trying different `spec` options) but all of them will run all test on both mobile/non mobile browser. I need the test mobile test to run **only** on mobile, while all others on regular browser.

1. Do I have a programatically way of doing this during my test (and not using config)?
2. What am I doing wrong with my current config? Why isn't `specs` working for me?

Answer (score 2):

After reading [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/605) post I figured out that the problem is that the capability-specific specs are **in addition** to the main config.specs.

This means I have to remove the defaults arrived from my infrastructure config file, using `specs: []`

```
'use strict';

var config = require('infra-gruntfile/protractor-conf').config;

// old capabilities
// config.capabilities = {
//   browserName: 'chrome'
// };

config.specs = []; //This line solved my problem!

config.multiCapabilities =
[
  {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    name: 'Unnamed Job',
    count: 1,
    shardTestFiles: false,
    maxInstances: 10,
    chromeOptions: {
      'mobileEmulation': {
        'deviceName': 'Apple iPhone 4'
      },
      args: [
        'incognito',
        'disable-extensions'
      ]
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
      browser: 'ALL'
    },
    specs: ['app/**/*.mobile.spec.js']
  },
  {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['!app/**/*.mobile.spec.js']
  }
]

module.exports.config = config;
```